# Could an equation like ${^{h}b} = b^h + $c together with polynomial interpolation be used to calculate tetration? Are there flaws in it?

Tags: approximation, tetration

As it is quite easy to calculate integer solutions for $\;^hb = b^h $ the question arose on how to find a solution for real heights.
One idea was of predicting the height by finding a formula approximating it. For more on that specific equation see [Might results which show the same result for tetration as for exponentiation be of any use (like in the range from 2 to e^(1/e))?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815905/might-results-which-show-the-same-result-for-tetration-as-for-exponentiation-be) . However this just gives probably just one solution for one base between 2 and $e^{1/e} $ and so I thought of changing it to $\;^hb = b^h + c $ which can just be approximated or simplified to $\; ^hb \approx c$ .

I tried with different constants and decided to use Newton's divided differences interpolation polynomial method to get a good approximation
for the desired interval as predicting the whole series of solutions from $2$ to infinity with some self-made formula seemed to be hopeless as it would never be exact enough -- especially for lower heights. It turned out it just needed to be pretty good in the range from $3$ to $4$ for base $e$ and $4$ to $5$ in for base $2$. I tried with different numbers of polynomials and different constants.

Of interested was just the non-integer or fractional value due to the unique property of tetration where $\; ({^{b}a})^{(^{c}a)} = ({^{(c+1)}a}) ^ {({^{(b-1)}a})}$.
From this can be concluded that from a tetrational height $x$ between 0 and 1 all other heights n+x can be calculated where $n$ is any integer greater than $0$.

## Results

I used a constant c of $\;^4(2.1) $ ~ 84899120142.81 to predict the calculated value for $\;^4b = c $ and the best prediction was around 2.15 instead of the calculated 2.1000003814697266. Then I supposed it would behave like $2^x $ and used multiplication to get more values and then I used the Newton polynomial method to get an approximation and the result was the formula $1 + 0.6856427806944169 x + 0.22005174698143642 x^2 + 0.07447687052884291x^3$.

In a similar way I used different constants to get solutions for $\;^3b = c $ and from the results I used Newton polynomials to get a formula or function which approximates the exponential function which pretty good approximates $\;^xe $ for $0 > x < 1 $. The result was $1 + 1.0432362881329733 x + 0.5910113778264401 x^2$.

Please take a look at https://github.com/MatthiasLiszt/tetrationalPlayground/ to see graphs and code.